# DataBinding in DataGrid within Tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a main window with the following TabControl, inside the TabItem there is a DataGrid that should display the Businesses within a Section but can't resolve the Binding between the Section and the grid

Here is the code:

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    static MainWindow () {
        MainCatalog = Catalog.Instance;
    }

    public MainWindow () {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = MainCatalog;
        BusinessesGrid.DataContext = MainCatalog.FoodSection;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<TabControl x:Name="SectionControl" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="386">
            <TabItem Header="Food Section">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="375">
                    <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="15,13,0,0"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Search" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" />
                    <Button x:Name="SerchButton" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,13,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
                    <Button x:Name="AddButton" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,13,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" />
                    <Button x:Name="RemoveButton" Content="-" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,13,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.4,0.682" />
                    <DataGrid x:Name="BusinessesGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="15,53,0,0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" ItemsSource="{Binding Catalog}"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Section Class:

```
public class Section : SearchBinaryTree < BinaryTreeNode < Business >,Business > {

    public Section ( string name ) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Section ( BinaryTreeNode < Business > root, string name ) : base( root ) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection < Business > Catalog {
        get { return GetCatalog(); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection < Business > GetCatalog () {
        var businesses = new ObservableCollection < Business >();
        InOrder( businesses.Add );

        return businesses;
    }
}
```

Catalog Class has Four sections:

```
public class Catalog {

        public Section FoodSection { get; }
        public Section SchoolSection { get; }
        public Section BeautySection { get; }
        public Section FunSection { get; }

        public static Catalog Instance { get; }

        static Catalog () {
            Instance = new Catalog();
        }

        private Catalog ( ) {
            FoodSection = new Section("Food");
            SchoolSection = new Section("School");
            BeautySection = new Section("Beauty");
            FunSection = new Section("Fun");
        }

    }
```

So the data grid has a ItemsSource attribute but it is not working, I'm new to WPF, does anyone has any ideas???

Comment: Have you checked Visual Studios Output window for binding errors? That could give a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line of code as no need to set the DataContext of the `DataGrid`

```
BusinessesGrid.DataContext = MainCatalog.FoodSection;
```

as you've already set the `DataContext` of the page to MainCatelog you should just have to set the `ItemsSource` of **BusinessGrid** to FoodSection

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BusinessesGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="15,53,0,0"
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" ItemsSource="{Binding FoodSection}"/>
```